# How to check the convergence when fitting a distribution in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, model-fitting, convergence

**Is there a way to check the convergence when fitting a distribution in SciPy?**

My goal is to fit a SciPy distribution (namely Johnson S_U distr.) to dozens of datasets as a part of an automated data-monitoring system. Mostly it works fine, but a few datasets are anomalous and clearly do not follow the Johnson S_U distribution. Fits on these datasets diverge *silently*, i.e. without any warning/error/whatever! On the contrary, if I switch to R and try to fit there I never ever get a convergence, which is correct - regardless of the fit settings, the R algorithm denies to declare a convergence.

data:
Two datasets are [available in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/urwa611l8n5uudv/AADlFuOpUt3e2hxbqr7i_gfHa?dl=0):

- `data-converging-fit.csv` ... a standard data where fit converges nicely (*you may think this is an ugly, skewed and heavy-central-mass blob but the Johnson S_U is flexible enough to fit such a beast!*):

[image]

- `data-diverging-fit.csv` ... an anomalous data where fit diverges:

[image]

code to fit the distribution:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

distribution_name = 'johnsonsu'
dist = getattr(stats, distribution_name)

convdata = pd.read_csv('data-converging-fit.csv', index_col= 'timestamp')
divdata  = pd.read_csv('data-diverging-fit.csv', index_col= 'timestamp')
```

On the good data, the fitted parameters have common order of magnitude:

```py
a, b, loc, scale = dist.fit(convdata['target'])
a, b, loc, scale

[out]: (0.3154946859186918, 
 2.9938226613743932,
 0.002176043693009398,
 0.045430055488776266)
```

On the anomalous data, the fitted parameters are unreasonable:

```py
a, b, loc, scale = dist.fit(divdata['target'])
a, b, loc, scale

[out]: (-3424954.6481554992, 
7272004.43156841, 
-71078.33596490842, 
145478.1300979394)
```

Still I get no single line of warning that the fit failed to converge.

From researching similar questions on StackOverflow, I know the suggestion to bin my data and then use `curve_fit`. Despite its practicality, that solution is not right in my opinion, since that is not the way we fit distributions: the binning is arbitrary (the nr. of bins) and it affects the final fit. A more realistic option might be `scipy.optimize.minimize` and callbacks to learn the progrss of convergence; still I am not sure that it will eventually tell me whether the algorithm converged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `johnsonu.fit` method comes from `scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit`. Unfortunately from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) it does not appear that it is possible to get any more information about the fit from this method.

However, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2334-L2514), it appears the actual optimization is done with [`fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html), which does return more descriptive parameters. You could borrow from the source code and write your own implementation of `fit` that checks the `fmin` output parameters for convergence:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import optimize, stats

distribution_name = 'johnsonsu'
dist = getattr(stats, distribution_name)

convdata = pd.read_csv('data-converging-fit.csv', index_col= 'timestamp')
divdata  = pd.read_csv('data-diverging-fit.csv', index_col= 'timestamp')

def custom_fit(dist, data, method="mle"):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    start = dist._fitstart(data)
    args = [start[0:-2], (start[-2], start[-1])]
    x0, func, restore, args = dist._reduce_func(args, {}, data=data)
    vals = optimize.fmin(func, x0, args=(np.ravel(data),))
    return vals
```

```py
custom_fit(dist, convdata['target'])

[out]: Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -23423.995945
         Iterations: 162
         Function evaluations: 274
array([3.15494686e-01, 2.99382266e+00, 2.17604369e-03, 4.54300555e-02])
```

```
custom_fit(dist, divdata['target'])

[out]: Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.
array([-12835849.95223926,  27253596.647191  ,   -266388.68675908,
          545225.46661612])
```

Comment: Thank you, @turnerm, this confirmation ("you need to write your own `fit()` mthod") is exactly what I was after! I appreciate the code too.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the right approach is to do a statistical test of the fitted parameters. Then you'll be able to set the significance level and accept/reject the hypothesis that the data follows this distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @ev-br. Initially, I have folowed the approach you're suggesting; still it did not reveal the divergence issue. And I am reluctant to believe there is no way to find out the fit is diverging in SciPy...